# How do I break a do while loop when two 2D arrays become exactly the same?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, do-while

I have a project for uni that needs me to create a crossword puzzle using 2 D arrays. I have done some progress, but have stuck on the part where if the user solves the puzzle correctly, it keeps looping. I need help with breaking out of the loop when both of the arrays are completely the same meaning the puzzle has been solved! Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HI! This is a crossword puzzle using 2D arrays in JAVA!");
        System.out.println("There are 5 words in total, that you have to guess!");
        System.out.println("Each letter must be in place of the empty space. Each letter must be wrote in full caps!.");

        char[][] correctPuzzle = {{' ','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', ' '},
                                  {'|','C','|', 'H', '|', 'A', '|','R', '|', '■', '|'},
                                  {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                                  {'|','L','|', 'O', '|', 'O', '|','P', '|', '■', '|'},
                                  {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                                  {'|','A','|', '■', '|', '■', '|','■', '|', 'I', '|'},
                                  {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                                  {'|','S','|', 'U', '|', 'M', '|','■', '|', 'N', '|'},
                                  {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                                  {'|','S','|', '■', '|', '■', '|','■', '|', 'T', '|'},
                                  {' ','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', ' '},};

        char[][] defaultPuzzle = {{' ','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', ' '},
                {'|',' ','|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|',' ', '|', '■', '|'},
                {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                {'|',' ','|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|',' ', '|', '■', '|'},
                {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                {'|',' ','|', '■', '|', '■', '|','■', '|', ' ', '|'},
                {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                {'|',' ','|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|','■', '|', ' ', '|'},
                {'|','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', '|'},
                {'|',' ','|', '■', '|', '■', '|','■', '|', ' ', '|'},
                {' ','—','—', '—', '—', '—', '—','—', '—', '—', ' '},};

        int option;
        do{
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                    System.out.print(defaultPuzzle[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Question 1 (1st column) What is blueprint for an object?");
            System.out.println("Question 2 (1st row) What data type represents a single character?");
            System.out.println("Question 3 (2nd row) Feature used to execute a particular part of the program repeatedly");
            System.out.println("Question 4 (4th row) Synonym for the word result - used in programming");
            System.out.println("Question 5 (5th column) Abbreviation of the word integer");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Which question would you like to answer? ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int ansNum = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Input your guess! ");
            String guess;
            switch(ansNum) {
                case 1:
                    guess = sc.next();
                    if(guess.length() == 5) {
                        for(int rowNo = 1, charNo = 0; charNo < guess.length(); rowNo+=2, charNo++){
                            defaultPuzzle[rowNo][1] = guess.charAt(charNo);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect answer length!");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    guess = sc.next();
                    if(guess.length() == 4) {
                        for(int collNo = 1, charNo = 0; charNo < guess.length(); collNo+=2, charNo++){
                            defaultPuzzle[1][collNo] = guess.charAt(charNo);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect answer length!");
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    guess = sc.next();
                    if(guess.length() == 4) {
                        for(int collNo = 1, charNo = 0; charNo < guess.length(); collNo+=2, charNo++){
                            defaultPuzzle[3][collNo] = guess.charAt(charNo);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect answer length!");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                guess = sc.next();
                if(guess.length() == 3) {
                    for(int collNo = 1, charNo = 0; charNo < guess.length(); collNo+=2, charNo++){
                        defaultPuzzle[7][collNo] = guess.charAt(charNo);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect answer length!");
                }
                break;

                case 5:
                    guess = sc.next();
                    if(guess.length() == 3) {
                        for(int rowNo = 5, charNo = 0; charNo < guess.length(); rowNo+=2, charNo++){
                            defaultPuzzle[rowNo][9] = guess.charAt(charNo);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect answer length!");
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("This answer doesn't exist. Please select 1-5!!!");

            }


            System.out.println("If you want to continue and see your progress, press 1");
            System.out.println("Is you are struggling and want to see the correct answers, press 2");
            option = sc.nextInt();


        }
        while(option == 1);
        if(option == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                System.out.print(correctPuzzle[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Better luck next time! These were the correct answers!");
        }
        else if (equals(correctPuzzle, defaultPuzzle)) {
            System.out.print("Congratulations! You have solved the  puzzle");
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                    System.out.print(correctPuzzle[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }
        }

    }
public static boolean equals(char[][] a, char[][] b) {
        if (a.length != b.length)
            return false;
        for(char i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}
}
```

I have tried adding a 6th switch statement with a condition if the arrays match it will break, but it doesn't work. I have tried adding a condition to the while(option == 1 && correctPuzzle == defaultPuzzle), but that doesn't seem to work either. And lastly I have created a method to compare the arrays, and I'm not confident with this because it was a last resort effort.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things I would suggest changing about the code, specifically moving things into lots of different methods outside of main to make your code a lot more readable and easier to debug.

But I believe that your error is in how you're checking array equality. I don't know how you were checking it before adding your own `equals` method but your `equals` method doesn't work.

By default doing `myArray == myArray2` or `myArray.equals(myArray2)` will return a reference equals, meaning they check if they're the exact same array by object reference

You can use the Arrays library to match if you don't want write your own method:
`Arrays.deepEquals(myArray, myArray2)`
You can use this to check the entire 2D array.

For example: if you have a piece of paper (paper1) the the word "dog" on it and another one (paper2) with the word "dog" on it
`paper1 == paper2` will tell you they're not the same because they're 2 different pieces of paper but `Arrays.deepEquals(paper, paper2)` will tell you that the content contained on the paper are the same.

If you want to write your own method you're going to need a nested for loop to check each char in each char array in your 2D array:

```java
    public static boolean equals(char[][] a, char[][] b){
        for(int row = 0; row < a.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++){
                if(a[row][col] != b[row][col]) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```